# USRP Sink Warning: Sensor 'ref_locked' failed to lock within timeout on motherboard 0

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, software-defined-radio

while running the following flow graph in a USRP B210, I am getting the warning: "usrp_sink :warning: Sensor 'ref_locked' failed to lock within timeout on motherboard 0.". How can I fix this and what is exactly the issue? The LO doesn't get to the requested frequency before some timeout?

[image]